# How to put failed custom object of javax.mail.Message into jms queue (using Activemq)

Tags: activemq-classic, jakarta-mail

I am creating utiltiy which send mail using my outlook account, to do so I am creating object of javax.mail.Message and send it, if message sending is failed due to SendingFailedException, I want to add those messages into jms queue, and at the other end listener will run at every 10 min interval to consume these messages from the queue and try to resend those messages.

I have gone through some of the stackoverflow topics related to same, they instructed to change message into xml or in JSON, I just want to know how to deal with it, if that would be the way to implement this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [MimeMessage.writeTo method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) you can turn the message into a byte stream.  Collect it in a ByteArrayOutputStream and then include the bytes in the JMS message.  At the other end, you can reconstitute the message using the [MimeMessage constructor that takes an InputStream](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage-javax.mail.Session-java.io.InputStream-).

For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
msg.writeTo(bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
// put the data in a JMS message

// in the receiver, extract the byte array from the message
byte[] data = ...
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, data);
```

Sorry, I can't help you with the JMS part.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I would appreciate if you can please provide more details on the same (if you have any example)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill for your help.